# get JSON value by Key in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I have the following markup and component.

**new.component.html**

```
<a routerLink="{{sub.name}}" routerLinkActive="active">{{sub.name}}</a>
```

**old.component.ts**

```
data;

this.route.params.subscribe((params:any) => {console.log(params)})
```

console is output this as `{"sub.name" : "ABC"}`

But, when I call `console.log(params.sub.name)` to get "ABC", it says name is `undefined`!

What I missed here?

Comment: use params["sub.name"]

Comment: This is a basic object's member access pattern and has nothing to do with Angular.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because the key is "sub.name", so you have to call this:

```
console.log(params["sub.name"]);
```

Cheers!